# Why does -mprefer-vector-width=128 run 3x faster than -mprefer-vector-width=512 for implicitly vectorized code?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, avx512, auto-vectorization

With Godbolt.org benchmarking:

- `-march=native`: https://godbolt.org/z/Ys6rqbGGe
- `-march=cascadelake`: https://godbolt.org/z/W3EM5hKsq

the -mprefer-vector-width=128 flag makes it complete sqrt operation in 0.67 cycles while -mprefer-vector-width=512 causes it to complete sqrt operation in 1.95 cycles.

Source code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include<cmath>
template<typename Type, int Simd>
struct KernelData
{
    alignas(32)
    Type data[Simd];

    inline void readFrom(const Type * const __restrict__ ptr) noexcept
    {
        #pragma GCC ivdep
        for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
        {
            data[i] = ptr[i];
        }
    }

    inline void writeTo(Type * const __restrict__ ptr) const noexcept
    {
        #pragma GCC ivdep
        for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = data[i];
        }
    }

    inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> sqrt() const noexcept
    {
        KernelData<Type,Simd> result;
        #pragma GCC ivdep
        for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
        {
            result.data[i] = std::sqrt(data[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
};




template<int mask>
struct KernelDataFactory
{
    KernelDataFactory()
    {

    }


    template<typename Type>
    inline
    KernelData<Type,mask> generate() const
    {
        return KernelData<Type,mask>();
    }
};

template<int SimdWidth, typename... Args>
class Kernel
{
public:
    Kernel(std::function<void(int,int, Args...)> kernelPrm)
    {
        kernel = kernelPrm;
    }


    void run(int n, Args... args)
    {
        const int nLoop = (n/SimdWidth);
        for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
        {
            kernel(i*SimdWidth,SimdWidth, args...);
        }

        if((n/SimdWidth)*SimdWidth != n)
        {
            const int m = n%SimdWidth;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                kernel(nLoop*SimdWidth+i,1, args...);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::function<void(int,int, Args...)> kernel;
};

// cpu cycles from stackoverflow
#include <stdint.h>  // <cstdint> is preferred in C++, but stdint.h works.
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# include <intrin.h>
#else
# include <x86intrin.h>
#endif
inline
uint64_t readTSC() {
    // _mm_lfence();  // optionally wait for earlier insns to retire before reading the clock
    uint64_t tsc = __rdtsc();
    // _mm_lfence();  // optionally block later instructions until rdtsc retires
    return tsc;
}

int main(int argC, char** argV)
{ 
    constexpr int simd = 16;    
    constexpr int n = 1003;
    Kernel<simd, float *, float *> kernel([](int simdGroupId, int simdWidth, float * input, float * output){
        const int id = simdGroupId;
        if(simdWidth == simd)
        {
            const KernelDataFactory<simd> factory;
            auto a = factory.generate<float>();

            a.readFrom(input+id);
            const auto b = a.sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().
            sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().
            sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt();
            b.writeTo(output+id);
        }
        else
        {
            const KernelDataFactory<1> factory;
            auto a = factory.generate<float>();

            a.readFrom(input+id);
            const auto b = a.sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().
            sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().
            sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt().sqrt();
            b.writeTo(output+id);
        }
    });
  
    alignas(32)
    float i[n],o[n];
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        i[j]=j;
    auto t1 = readTSC();
    for(int k=0;k<10000;k++)
        kernel.run(n,i,o);
    auto t2 = readTSC();
    for(int i=n-10;i<n;i++)
    {

        std::cout<<"i="<<i<<" value="<<o[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<0.0001f*(t2-t1)/(float)(15*n)<<" cycles per sqrt"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt output for 128 bit preference (-std=c++2a  -O3 -march=native -mprefer-vector-width=128 -ftree-vectorize -fno-math-errno  -lpthread):

```
    push    rbp
    add     rsi, rcx
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -32
    sub     rsp, 8
    vsqrtps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
    vsqrtps xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+16]
    vsqrtps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
    vsqrtps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+48]
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vsqrtps xmm0, xmm0
    vsqrtps xmm3, xmm3
    vsqrtps xmm2, xmm2
    vsqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm3
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm2
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-8], xmm1
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
    vmovdqa xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+16], xmm4
    vmovdqa xmm5, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+32], xmm5
    vmovdqa xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-8]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+48], xmm6
    leave
    ret
```

Godbolt output for 512 bit preference (-std=c++2a  -O3 -march=native -mprefer-vector-width=512 -ftree-vectorize -fno-math-errno  -lpthread):

```
    push    rbp
    add     rsi, rcx
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -64
    sub     rsp, 8
    vmovdqu xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
    vmovdqu xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+16]
    vmovdqu xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
    vmovdqu xmm5, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+48]
    vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp-120], xmm2
    vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp-104], xmm3
    vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp-88], xmm4
    vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp-72], xmm5
    vsqrtps zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [rsp-120]
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vsqrtps zmm0, zmm0
    vmovaps ZMMWORD PTR [rsp-56], zmm0
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
    vmovdqa xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+16], xmm6
    vmovdqa xmm7, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+32], xmm7
    vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-8]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+48], xmm1
    vzeroupper
    leave
    ret
```

How does AVX512-related packed square root operation run a lot slower than 128bit?

Comment: Maybe the movs at the begining of the AVX512 case? I guess it spends too much time to mov the values into the proper registers before it can call the AVX512 instruction.
Also NEVER!!!! use `-march=native` on godbolt!!!!

Comment: What compiler?  GCC and clang both support those options?  What CPU are you benchmarking on?

Comment: Is march=native bad because it may run on non-avx512? Benchmarking fx8150 and Godbolt's server (which slowsdown with 512bit preference).

Comment: `-march=native` on Godbolt is bad because the code-gen choices depend what CPU the AWS instance happens to run on.  Currently it's Cascade Lake, I think, but might be Ice Lake server at some point, or years from now could be some future uarch like Sapphire Rapids or later.  It's not totally crazy if you're benchmarking something yourself using Godbolt's AWS instances, but it's not a good idea to use in Godbolt links you're posting somewhere, since future readers could see different codegen.

Comment: Your XMM version has 4 dep chains, your ZMM has one.  Assuming Cascade Lake (you can check `-fverbose-asm` output), XMM sqrtps has 12 to 13c latency, 3c throughput.  But ZMM has about 20c latency, 12c throughput.  So the same total max throughput, you're just not achieving it because you bottleneck on sqrt latency.  https://uops.info/ And the dep chain is too long for OoO exec to fully hide it, I guess.  Loop unrolling would help.

Comment: Oh also, you have 4x XMM stores and a ZMM reload, causing a store-forwarding stall which also costs extra latency in that dep chain, making it harder for OoO exec to hide.

Comment: @PeterCordes added cascadelake-link. Perhaps instructions stay same in future (if not performance). When I try making simd=256 (for OoO) it doesn't get faster I guess because hardware registers don't have enough space.

Comment: @PeterCordes the EC instances that the CE team use are just all over the places. I guess the EC's cpu is simply *undetermined* . That is, today it can be either skylake xeon, cascadelake xeon or icelake xeon. This means when you try to use `-march=native` with CE, it can be anything in those I mentioned at the moment it compiles. Yes, this means you can't do accurate benchmark on CE executors because of this neither. [[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fW9z1vPeG)]

Comment: @sandthorn: Yeah, and you're potentially sharing the CPU with other workloads, so benchmarking on Godbolt is very unreliable even if you include code to print out a CPUID result so you know what you ran on.  https://quick-bench.com/ times against a NOP loop to try to calibrate for the non-idle system (click its "about" menu), but doesn't allow specifying build options.  (You could use a `#pragma target` and maybe include code to print CPUID output.)  For a while, Godbolt sometimes ran on Zen 3 cores, so AVX-512 code would SIGILL.  (And `-march=native` wouldn't include AVX-512.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. It can run the undocumented FMA4!! Though it also runs `AVX512` too. I guess some ECs might include EPYC. I never thought now the EPYC can do `AVX512BITALG` like icelake. [[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/absT7dbWo)]  The AWS EC is kinda messy, baremetal-wise.

Comment: @sandthorn: You must be getting a Zen 4 EPYC instance if AVX-512 worked but it wasn't Intel; Zen 4's AVX-512 extensions include everything Ice Lake has, plus BF16 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512).  Zen 3 doesn't have AVX-512 at all.  (FMA4 was only present-but-undocumented in Zen 1; Zen 2 actually dropped it.  Unless you're saying Zen 3 reintroduced it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The CE seems to be able to have both `FMA4` and `AVX512BITALG` at the same time. I guess perhaps Zen 4 revives it.

Comment: @sandthorn:  If you add `-mfma4` to the compiler window (not just the executor which you made separate for some reason), we can see that GCC and clang compiled `_mm256_macc_ps` into an FMA3 instruction (`vfmadd132ps     ymm0, ymm1, ymm2` with 3 operands), because it didn't need or want the non-destructive FMA4 to put the result in a 4th output without overwriting any of the 3 inputs.  https://compiler-explorer.com/z/oWjaGbsMe .  The occasional SIGILL we see is from non-IceLake instances getting to that part.

Comment: @sandthorn: I added `fflush(stdout)` after each of the `fmt::print` calls, so we could see what succeeded before SIGILL.  https://compiler-explorer.com/z/E7e3fsPPc shows FMA4 intrinsic always succeeds, (because compiles to an FMA3 instruction); the occasional segfaults are due to other targets.  Surprisingly, putting a `print` between fill and `macc_ps` *does* get compilers to use an FMA4 instruction, so it always SIGILLs on the FMA: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fvonjcqx3 (because none of the servers are Zen 1).  This is a missed optimization; FMA3 is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @sandthorn: When compiling with `-march=sapphirerapids`, this leads to AVX-512 code-gen inside `fmt` for clang (which doesn't use an FMA4), so on Zen 3 instances we can get a SIGILL for that reason with only the `after rdrand, before FMA` print being visible.  I changed to using `-march=native -mfma4` with `#ifdef __AVX512F__` and `#warning` blocks so we could see what features -march=native was using.  (Still have to manually inspect the code-gen for FMA4 vs. FMA3.) https://compiler-explorer.com/z/d7sefxzfq  The recompile button (bottom left of the asm pane) sometimes gets no AVX512 (zen3)

Comment: Clang does sometimes use FMA4 depending on what architecture `-march=native` picks, so it will still sometimes SIGILL; you have to check the asm every time.  Anyway, I find no evidence that any CPU we ever get on AWS supports an FMA4 asm instruction.  AMD hasn't reintroduced it on Zen 3 or Zen 4.

Comment: @PeterCordes I can't reason why `gcc` somehow switches from `AVX512F` to `FMA4` when there are any calls preceeded. `clang` is just insisting to stick with `AVX512F` . You're right `FMA4` has no supported, all go `SIGILL` everytime. I guess currently in AWS EC there might be Intel cascadelake, icelake and AMD zen2, zen3 epyc which is reson why `AVX512F` triggers `SIGILL` . There are no signs of sapphire rapids and zen 4 for now. [[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/33rTbdf5z)] BTW if you seperate executor, you can reload binary and rerun it way quicker. Click graph icon on executors.

Comment: @sandthorn: `vfmadd231ps` with YMM registers is FMA3 (`-mfma`), available since Haswell and Piledriver, not AVX512F.  That's why it runs on Zen 3 instances that lack AVX-512.  Yeah, IDK why GCC picks the less compact instruction in some cases when it doesn't save instructions, when both FMA3 and FMA4 are available.